# error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'log'

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I wrote some functions,and complied it to a dll module .In my header file as followed:

```
#ifndef GET_DATAFEED_FORKDB_H
#define GET_DATAFEED_FORKDB_H

#include "..\include\stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#include "..\include\TDFAPI.h"
#include "..\include\TDFAPIStruct.h"
#include "..\include\PathHelper.h"
#include "..\include\ConfigSettings.h"

// some helper functions
// ....

extern "C" void openConnect();
extern "C" void closeConnect();

#endif
```

However,when I used Visual Studio 2013 Professional to compile it, i got some errors:

```
F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(501) :
  error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for  'log'
F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(501) : 
 see declaration of 'log'
F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtgmath.h(104)
  :error C2732: linkage specification 
  contradicts earlier specification for 'log'
F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtgmath.h(104)
  : see declaration of 'log'
F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337)
  : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not 
   enabled. Specify /EHsc
```

I have not use math method. so I tried to use [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/726yhbsw.aspx) to solve it, but it did not work. The included head files can't not modified, I also tried use this method:

```
 extern "C" {
    #include "..\include\TDFAPI.h"
    #include "..\include\TDFAPIStruct.h"
    #include "..\include\k.h"
    #include "..\include\PathHelper.h"
    #include "..\include\ConfigSettings.h"
  }
```

,what's worse, it occurred more errors.

Comment: If you're not using math library, why'd you need the header anyway?

Comment: @cremno, I did not call any math function, and define math function named log.

Comment: @SouravGhosh,I did not include math header.But In my header file, I declared some functions like this:extern "C" void openConnect();
extern "C" void closeConnect();

Comment: Then you need to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and remove the C tag.

Comment: @cremno，Thanks your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I just come across the same problem as you. I have encountered the same problem as you. The `#include "k.h"` must be put after including any std headers.